# How to give all my web page links opening delay?

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to know if anyone has had any experience with time delays? I'm trying to get all my global links to open with a time delay. Just to give it an artistic effect, make it swap pages more smoothly.But for some reason I cannot get it working. I'd appreciate any help I can get.

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/mainstyle.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
        <title> Redneck Rampage </title>
    </head>
    <body class="filter">
    <div id="background"> 
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul id="mainmenu">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>   
            <li><a href="band.html">Band</a></li>  
            <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shows.html">Shows</a></li>
                    <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>

                <div class="footer homepage">
                    <p class="rednecks">Website and Contents &copy; Redneck Rampage 2013. </p>
                    <p class="signature">Designed by Martin Metsalu </p>

                        <ul id="footermenu">
                            <li><a href="terms.html">Terms of use</a></li>
                            <li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    <div class="socialplugins">
                        <div class="test"><a href="#"><img src="IMG/soundcloud.png" alt="plugin#1" ></a></div>        
                        <div class="test"><a href="#"><img src="IMG/youtube.png" alt="plugin#2"></a></div>
                        <div class="test"><a href="#"><img src="IMG/myspace.png" alt="plugin#3"></a></div>
                        <div class="test"><a href="#"><img src="IMG/facebook.png" alt="plugin#4"></a></div>

                    </div>

                </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
        $('a').click(function(e) {
$('a[href*="/steve"]').each(function(index) {
    setTimeout(
         function(href){window.open(href)},
         (index+1)*5000, $(this).attr('href')
    );
});
```

Comment: Add a `return false` after the setTimeout.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? When the user clicks a link, you want the click event to be delayed? Or you just want pages to consecutively start opening in new windows every 5 seconds? From the code and description, it looks like you're trying to do one of the two, either way both are *terrible* usability choices.

Comment: I figured because some pages contain more content than the other I give them a time delay (not necesseraly 5 sec). But I suppose that will only execute the click command with a delay. The content will still take time to load after that, am I right? If so, how do I preload the content to make the web experience less mechanical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( 'a[href*="/steve"]' ).each( function () {
    $( this ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ( function ( h ) {
            setTimeout( function () {
                window.location = h;
            }, 5000 );
        })( this.href );
    });
});
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Gave it a try. Didn't get any results. Here is the markup of my code: https://github.com/ISynesthesiaI/Stack-Overflow

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add an extra "star" symbol. Replaced the first line of code with: **$( 'a[href*="*.html"]' ).each( function () {**  THANKS FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do `e.preventDefault();` at the top of your click function